# How to access all of user's contacts in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cncontact

I am writing an app (swift 3) where I would like the user to be able to select any of their address book contacts to perform some actions with them. I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore) for it and recognize that I need to use `CNContactStore` but don't understand much else from it. There are several fetch functions that include `withIdentifier` but I want them to be able to access any one of their contacts, so I will not know which identifier to use until *after* they have selected them. So how can i fetch all of their data to allow the user to make their choice?

Comment: " I would prefer to just use the following to wrap the individual functions as opposed to the entire class" But the code you are showing does _not_ wrap an individual function. That's the problem. You don't use `if #available` to mark a function. However, I treat that as a separate question.

Comment: The entire thing was supposed to be a function, my bad. However, nothing changes if I put a function in there. I still get an error

Comment: Nvm, I see what you mean

Comment: Before you worry about `CNContactStore`, you may first want to present a UI to let the user pick a contact, so you don't write your own contact picking UI. For this, you use the [ContactsUI.framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui). Frankly, I'd suggest starting with WWDC 2015 [Introducing the Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/223/), which talks about both Contacts and ContactsUI frameworks.